# Flutter Desktop (macOS, Linux, Windows) - How to deliver code updates?

Tags: flutter

Delivering client updates is important for future compatibility of our product. Obviously, the desktop storefront can issue application updates and assist with managing that process. However, many of the popular developer tools in use today can be downloaded directly from the developer's website.

Is there a solution that allows me to package a Flutter desktop application and deliver updates without needing something like an App Store? Something that can download the updated binaries across launch and install them before the next launch?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package [auto_updater](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_updater), but it's only for Mac and Windows.

Another solution would be to install 2 apps: your main app and an updater. The main app checks at start if an update is required. If true, it executes the updater and terminates. The updater waits 2 seconds until the main app is terminated and downloads your new app files from server. After the download is done, the updater starts the updated app.

(Note that your main app can't update itself because it can't update files in use.)